# Find the highest and lowest value locations within an interval on a column?

Tags: pandas, max, grouping, min, series

Given this pandas dataframe with two columns, 'Values' and 'Intervals'. How do I get a third column 'MinMax' indicating whether the value is a maximum or a minimum within that interval? The challenge for me is that the interval length and the distance between intervals are not fixed, therefore I post the question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = pd.DataFrame([
        [1879.289,np.nan],[1879.281,np.nan],[1879.292,1],[1879.295,1],[1879.481,1],[1879.294,1],[1879.268,1],
        [1879.293,1],[1879.277,1],[1879.285,1],[1879.464,1],[1879.475,1],[1879.971,1],[1879.779,1],
        [1879.986,1],[1880.791,1],[1880.29,1],[1879.253,np.nan],[1878.268,np.nan],[1875.73,1],[1876.792,1],
        [1875.977,1],[1876.408,1],[1877.159,1],[1877.187,1],[1883.164,1],[1883.171,1],[1883.495,1],
        [1883.962,1],[1885.158,1],[1885.974,1],[1886.479,np.nan],[1885.969,np.nan],[1884.693,1],[1884.977,1],
        [1884.967,1],[1884.691,1],[1886.171,1],[1886.166,np.nan],[1884.476,np.nan],[1884.66,1],[1882.962,1],
        [1881.496,1],[1871.163,1],[1874.985,1],[1874.979,1],[1871.173,np.nan],[1871.973,np.nan],[1871.682,np.nan],
        [1872.476,np.nan],[1882.361,1],[1880.869,1],[1882.165,1],[1881.857,1],[1880.375,1],[1880.66,1],
        [1880.891,1],[1880.377,1],[1881.663,1],[1881.66,1],[1877.888,1],[1875.69,1],[1875.161,1],
        [1876.697,np.nan],[1876.671,np.nan],[1879.666,np.nan],[1877.182,np.nan],[1878.898,1],[1878.668,1],[1878.871,1],
        [1878.882,1],[1879.173,1],[1878.887,1],[1878.68,1],[1878.872,1],[1878.677,1],[1877.877,1],
        [1877.669,1],[1877.69,1],[1877.684,1],[1877.68,1],[1877.885,1],[1877.863,1],[1877.674,1],
        [1877.676,1],[1877.687,1],[1878.367,1],[1878.179,1],[1877.696,1],[1877.665,1],[1877.667,np.nan],
        [1878.678,np.nan],[1878.661,1],[1878.171,1],[1877.371,1],[1877.359,1],[1878.381,1],[1875.185,1],
        [1875.367,np.nan],[1865.492,np.nan],[1865.495,1],[1866.995,1],[1866.672,1],[1867.465,1],[1867.663,1],
        [1867.186,1],[1867.687,1],[1867.459,1],[1867.168,1],[1869.689,1],[1869.693,1],[1871.676,1],
        [1873.174,1],[1873.691,np.nan],[1873.685,np.nan]
    ])
```

In the third column below you can see where the max and min is for each interval.

```
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
| index |  Value   | Intervals | Min/Max |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
|     0 | 1879.289 | np.nan    |         |
|     1 | 1879.281 | np.nan    |         |
|     2 | 1879.292 | 1         |         |
|     3 | 1879.295 | 1         |         |
|     4 | 1879.481 | 1         |         |
|     5 | 1879.294 | 1         |         |
|     6 | 1879.268 | 1         | min     |
|     7 | 1879.293 | 1         |         |
|     8 | 1879.277 | 1         |         |
|     9 | 1879.285 | 1         |         |
|    10 | 1879.464 | 1         |         |
|    11 | 1879.475 | 1         |         |
|    12 | 1879.971 | 1         |         |
|    13 | 1879.779 | 1         |         |
|    17 | 1879.986 | 1         |         |
|    18 | 1880.791 | 1         | max     |
|    19 |  1880.29 | 1         |         |
|    55 | 1879.253 | np.nan    |         |
|    56 | 1878.268 | np.nan    |         |
|    57 |  1875.73 | 1         |         |
|    58 | 1876.792 | 1         |         |
|    59 | 1875.977 | 1         | min     |
|    60 | 1876.408 | 1         |         |
|    61 | 1877.159 | 1         |         |
|    62 | 1877.187 | 1         |         |
|    63 | 1883.164 | 1         |         |
|    64 | 1883.171 | 1         |         |
|    65 | 1883.495 | 1         |         |
|    66 | 1883.962 | 1         |         |
|    67 | 1885.158 | 1         |         |
|    68 | 1885.974 | 1         | max     |
|    69 | 1886.479 | np.nan    |         |
|    70 | 1885.969 | np.nan    |         |
|    71 | 1884.693 | 1         |         |
|    72 | 1884.977 | 1         |         |
|    73 | 1884.967 | 1         |         |
|    74 | 1884.691 | 1         | min     |
|    75 | 1886.171 | 1         | max     |
|    76 | 1886.166 | np.nan    |         |
|    77 | 1884.476 | np.nan    |         |
|    78 |  1884.66 | 1         | max     |
|    79 | 1882.962 | 1         |         |
|    80 | 1881.496 | 1         |         |
|    81 | 1871.163 | 1         | min     |
|    82 | 1874.985 | 1         |         |
|    83 | 1874.979 | 1         |         |
|    84 | 1871.173 | np.nan    |         |
|    85 | 1871.973 | np.nan    |         |
|    86 | 1871.682 | np.nan    |         |
|    87 | 1872.476 | np.nan    |         |
|    88 | 1882.361 | 1         | max     |
|    89 | 1880.869 | 1         |         |
|    90 | 1882.165 | 1         |         |
|    91 | 1881.857 | 1         |         |
|    92 | 1880.375 | 1         |         |
|    93 |  1880.66 | 1         |         |
|    94 | 1880.891 | 1         |         |
|    95 | 1880.377 | 1         |         |
|    96 | 1881.663 | 1         |         |
|    97 |  1881.66 | 1         |         |
|    98 | 1877.888 | 1         |         |
|    99 |  1875.69 | 1         |         |
|   100 | 1875.161 | 1         | min     |
|   101 | 1876.697 | np.nan    |         |
|   102 | 1876.671 | np.nan    |         |
|   103 | 1879.666 | np.nan    |         |
|   111 | 1877.182 | np.nan    |         |
|   112 | 1878.898 | 1         |         |
|   113 | 1878.668 | 1         |         |
|   114 | 1878.871 | 1         |         |
|   115 | 1878.882 | 1         |         |
|   116 | 1879.173 | 1         | max     |
|   117 | 1878.887 | 1         |         |
|   118 |  1878.68 | 1         |         |
|   119 | 1878.872 | 1         |         |
|   120 | 1878.677 | 1         |         |
|   121 | 1877.877 | 1         |         |
|   122 | 1877.669 | 1         |         |
|   123 |  1877.69 | 1         |         |
|   124 | 1877.684 | 1         |         |
|   125 |  1877.68 | 1         |         |
|   126 | 1877.885 | 1         |         |
|   127 | 1877.863 | 1         |         |
|   128 | 1877.674 | 1         |         |
|   129 | 1877.676 | 1         |         |
|   130 | 1877.687 | 1         |         |
|   131 | 1878.367 | 1         |         |
|   132 | 1878.179 | 1         |         |
|   133 | 1877.696 | 1         |         |
|   134 | 1877.665 | 1         | min     |
|   135 | 1877.667 | np.nan    |         |
|   136 | 1878.678 | np.nan    |         |
|   137 | 1878.661 | 1         | max     |
|   138 | 1878.171 | 1         |         |
|   139 | 1877.371 | 1         |         |
|   140 | 1877.359 | 1         |         |
|   141 | 1878.381 | 1         |         |
|   142 | 1875.185 | 1         | min     |
|   143 | 1875.367 | np.nan    |         |
|   144 | 1865.492 | np.nan    |         |
|   145 | 1865.495 | 1         | max     |
|   146 | 1866.995 | 1         |         |
|   147 | 1866.672 | 1         |         |
|   148 | 1867.465 | 1         |         |
|   149 | 1867.663 | 1         |         |
|   150 | 1867.186 | 1         |         |
|   151 | 1867.687 | 1         |         |
|   152 | 1867.459 | 1         |         |
|   153 | 1867.168 | 1         |         |
|   154 | 1869.689 | 1         |         |
|   155 | 1869.693 | 1         |         |
|   156 | 1871.676 | 1         |         |
|   157 | 1873.174 | 1         | min     |
|   158 | 1873.691 | np.nan    |         |
|   159 | 1873.685 | np.nan    |         |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Please make your data reproducible, random-seeded numbers would be best. Your `data = ...` line is so long (1024 char?) it blows up copy-and-paste in my shell.

Comment: I said that copying-and-pasting that line blows up my shell; the line is too long: 1024 chars or more. That line crashes my shell. That's why I suggested you use random-seeded numbers.

Comment: sorry, yes, i got that after i posted the comment :)

Comment: The problem is that i cannot reproduce this data with random seeds as the interval column can be of any size and of any length between it, so i do not know how to make it. That is why i pasted the entire datafarme

Comment: I can put a shorter version of it if that would help

Comment: Sure, like max 20 lines worth, and please do max 100 characters per line

Comment: What do you mean by *"the third column ('Interval') is for minimum and maximum within the interval between 1and 3 or -1 and -3"*? local min/max? min/max within a rolling n-point window?

Comment: what i meant is that in the third column i show where the max and min for each interval

Comment: The 'Interval' column is a real pain to deal with. It resists simple `groupby()`, because you don't want all 2's grouped together, you want each separate contiguous string of 1, then 2's, then3. So `data['Interval'] != 0` seems to be what we need to group.

Comment: if it helps, actually the values 1,2,3 or -1,-2,-3 from the intervals column can be converted to just 1 and then it's much simpler to group them. I will remake the data again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isnull = data.iloc[:, 1].isnull()
minmax = data.groupby(isnull.cumsum()[~isnull])[0].agg(['idxmax', 'idxmin'])
data.loc[minmax['idxmax'], 'MinMax'] = 'max'
data.loc[minmax['idxmin'], 'MinMax'] = 'min'
data.MinMax = data.MinMax.fillna('')
print(data)

            0    1 MinMax
0    1879.289  NaN       
1    1879.281  NaN       
2    1879.292  1.0       
3    1879.295  1.0       
4    1879.481  1.0       
5    1879.294  1.0       
6    1879.268  1.0    min
7    1879.293  1.0       
8    1879.277  1.0       
9    1879.285  1.0       
10   1879.464  1.0       
11   1879.475  1.0       
12   1879.971  1.0       
13   1879.779  1.0       
14   1879.986  1.0       
15   1880.791  1.0    max
16   1880.290  1.0       
17   1879.253  NaN       
18   1878.268  NaN       
19   1875.730  1.0    min
20   1876.792  1.0       
21   1875.977  1.0       
22   1876.408  1.0       
23   1877.159  1.0       
24   1877.187  1.0       
25   1883.164  1.0       
26   1883.171  1.0       
27   1883.495  1.0       
28   1883.962  1.0       
29   1885.158  1.0       
..        ...  ...    ...
85   1877.687  1.0       
86   1878.367  1.0       
87   1878.179  1.0       
88   1877.696  1.0       
89   1877.665  1.0    min
90   1877.667  NaN       
91   1878.678  NaN       
92   1878.661  1.0    max
93   1878.171  1.0       
94   1877.371  1.0       
95   1877.359  1.0       
96   1878.381  1.0       
97   1875.185  1.0    min
98   1875.367  NaN       
99   1865.492  NaN       
100  1865.495  1.0    min
101  1866.995  1.0       
102  1866.672  1.0       
103  1867.465  1.0       
104  1867.663  1.0       
105  1867.186  1.0       
106  1867.687  1.0       
107  1867.459  1.0       
108  1867.168  1.0       
109  1869.689  1.0       
110  1869.693  1.0       
111  1871.676  1.0       
112  1873.174  1.0    max
113  1873.691  NaN       
114  1873.685  NaN       

[115 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.columns=['Value','Interval']

data['Ingroup'] = (data['Interval'].notnull() + 0)

Use data['Interval'].notnull() to separate the groups...
Use cumsum() to number them with `groupno`...
Use groupby(groupno)..

Finally you want something using apply/idxmax/idxmin to label the max/min

But of course a for-loop as you suggested is the non-Pythonic but possibly simpler hack.
```

Comment: so what i want is for each interval (which can be between 1and3 or between -1and-3) in column "Intervals" to get the max and min from column "Value" in a separate column. Does this help understand better?

Comment: I changed the data now and replaced all value to 1. This is much simpler. Can you have a look over it. maybe it sparks some ideas for getting that min and max

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the guidance :) Much appreciated. If i could i would accept both answers as the correct ones ;)