# Numpy version of finding the highest and lowest value locations within an interval of another column?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

Given the following `numpy` array. How can I find the highest and lowest value locations of column 0 within the interval on column 1 using `numpy`?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
        [1879.289,np.nan],[1879.281,np.nan],[1879.292,1],[1879.295,1],[1879.481,1],[1879.294,1],[1879.268,1],
        [1879.293,1],[1879.277,1],[1879.285,1],[1879.464,1],[1879.475,1],[1879.971,1],[1879.779,1],
        [1879.986,1],[1880.791,1],[1880.29,1],[1879.253,np.nan],[1878.268,np.nan],[1875.73,1],[1876.792,1],
        [1875.977,1],[1876.408,1],[1877.159,1],[1877.187,1],[1883.164,1],[1883.171,1],[1883.495,1],
        [1883.962,1],[1885.158,1],[1885.974,1],[1886.479,np.nan],[1885.969,np.nan],[1884.693,1],[1884.977,1],
        [1884.967,1],[1884.691,1],[1886.171,1],[1886.166,np.nan],[1884.476,np.nan],[1884.66,1],[1882.962,1],
        [1881.496,1],[1871.163,1],[1874.985,1],[1874.979,1],[1871.173,np.nan],[1871.973,np.nan],[1871.682,np.nan],
        [1872.476,np.nan],[1882.361,1],[1880.869,1],[1882.165,1],[1881.857,1],[1880.375,1],[1880.66,1],
        [1880.891,1],[1880.377,1],[1881.663,1],[1881.66,1],[1877.888,1],[1875.69,1],[1875.161,1],
        [1876.697,np.nan],[1876.671,np.nan],[1879.666,np.nan],[1877.182,np.nan],[1878.898,1],[1878.668,1],[1878.871,1],
        [1878.882,1],[1879.173,1],[1878.887,1],[1878.68,1],[1878.872,1],[1878.677,1],[1877.877,1],
        [1877.669,1],[1877.69,1],[1877.684,1],[1877.68,1],[1877.885,1],[1877.863,1],[1877.674,1],
        [1877.676,1],[1877.687,1],[1878.367,1],[1878.179,1],[1877.696,1],[1877.665,1],[1877.667,np.nan],
        [1878.678,np.nan],[1878.661,1],[1878.171,1],[1877.371,1],[1877.359,1],[1878.381,1],[1875.185,1],
        [1875.367,np.nan],[1865.492,np.nan],[1865.495,1],[1866.995,1],[1866.672,1],[1867.465,1],[1867.663,1],
        [1867.186,1],[1867.687,1],[1867.459,1],[1867.168,1],[1869.689,1],[1869.693,1],[1871.676,1],
        [1873.174,1],[1873.691,np.nan],[1873.685,np.nan]
    ])
```

In the third column below you can see where the max and min is for each interval.

```
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
| index |  Value   | Intervals | Min/Max |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
|     0 | 1879.289 | np.nan    |         |
|     1 | 1879.281 | np.nan    |         |
|     2 | 1879.292 | 1         |         |
|     3 | 1879.295 | 1         |         |
|     4 | 1879.481 | 1         |         |
|     5 | 1879.294 | 1         |         |
|     6 | 1879.268 | 1         | -1      | min
|     7 | 1879.293 | 1         |         |
|     8 | 1879.277 | 1         |         |
|     9 | 1879.285 | 1         |         |
|    10 | 1879.464 | 1         |         |
|    11 | 1879.475 | 1         |         |
|    12 | 1879.971 | 1         |         |
|    13 | 1879.779 | 1         |         |
|    17 | 1879.986 | 1         |         |
|    18 | 1880.791 | 1         |  1      | max
|    19 |  1880.29 | 1         |         |
|    55 | 1879.253 | np.nan    |         |
|    56 | 1878.268 | np.nan    |         |
|    57 |  1875.73 | 1         | -1      |min
|    58 | 1876.792 | 1         |         |
|    59 | 1875.977 | 1         |         | 
|    60 | 1876.408 | 1         |         |
|    61 | 1877.159 | 1         |         |
|    62 | 1877.187 | 1         |         |
|    63 | 1883.164 | 1         |         |
|    64 | 1883.171 | 1         |         |
|    65 | 1883.495 | 1         |         |
|    66 | 1883.962 | 1         |         |
|    67 | 1885.158 | 1         |         |
|    68 | 1885.974 | 1         |  1      | max
|    69 | 1886.479 | np.nan    |         |
|    70 | 1885.969 | np.nan    |         |
|    71 | 1884.693 | 1         |         |
|    72 | 1884.977 | 1         |         |
|    73 | 1884.967 | 1         |         |
|    74 | 1884.691 | 1         | -1      | min
|    75 | 1886.171 | 1         |  1      | max
|    76 | 1886.166 | np.nan    |         |
|    77 | 1884.476 | np.nan    |         |
|    78 |  1884.66 | 1         |  1      | max
|    79 | 1882.962 | 1         |         |
|    80 | 1881.496 | 1         |         |
|    81 | 1871.163 | 1         | -1      | min
|    82 | 1874.985 | 1         |         |
|    83 | 1874.979 | 1         |         |
|    84 | 1871.173 | np.nan    |         |
|    85 | 1871.973 | np.nan    |         |
|    86 | 1871.682 | np.nan    |         |
|    87 | 1872.476 | np.nan    |         |
|    88 | 1882.361 | 1         |  1      | max
|    89 | 1880.869 | 1         |         |
|    90 | 1882.165 | 1         |         |
|    91 | 1881.857 | 1         |         |
|    92 | 1880.375 | 1         |         |
|    93 |  1880.66 | 1         |         |
|    94 | 1880.891 | 1         |         |
|    95 | 1880.377 | 1         |         |
|    96 | 1881.663 | 1         |         |
|    97 |  1881.66 | 1         |         |
|    98 | 1877.888 | 1         |         |
|    99 |  1875.69 | 1         |         |
|   100 | 1875.161 | 1         | -1      | min
|   101 | 1876.697 | np.nan    |         |
|   102 | 1876.671 | np.nan    |         |
|   103 | 1879.666 | np.nan    |         |
|   111 | 1877.182 | np.nan    |         |
|   112 | 1878.898 | 1         |         |
|   113 | 1878.668 | 1         |         |
|   114 | 1878.871 | 1         |         |
|   115 | 1878.882 | 1         |         |
|   116 | 1879.173 | 1         |  1      | max
|   117 | 1878.887 | 1         |         |
|   118 |  1878.68 | 1         |         |
|   119 | 1878.872 | 1         |         |
|   120 | 1878.677 | 1         |         |
|   121 | 1877.877 | 1         |         |
|   122 | 1877.669 | 1         |         |
|   123 |  1877.69 | 1         |         |
|   124 | 1877.684 | 1         |         |
|   125 |  1877.68 | 1         |         |
|   126 | 1877.885 | 1         |         |
|   127 | 1877.863 | 1         |         |
|   128 | 1877.674 | 1         |         |
|   129 | 1877.676 | 1         |         |
|   130 | 1877.687 | 1         |         |
|   131 | 1878.367 | 1         |         |
|   132 | 1878.179 | 1         |         |
|   133 | 1877.696 | 1         |         |
|   134 | 1877.665 | 1         | -1      | min
|   135 | 1877.667 | np.nan    |         |
|   136 | 1878.678 | np.nan    |         |
|   137 | 1878.661 | 1         |  1      | max
|   138 | 1878.171 | 1         |         |
|   139 | 1877.371 | 1         |         |
|   140 | 1877.359 | 1         |         |
|   141 | 1878.381 | 1         |         |
|   142 | 1875.185 | 1         | -1      | min
|   143 | 1875.367 | np.nan    |         |
|   144 | 1865.492 | np.nan    |         |
|   145 | 1865.495 | 1         |  -1     | min
|   146 | 1866.995 | 1         |         |
|   147 | 1866.672 | 1         |         |
|   148 | 1867.465 | 1         |         |
|   149 | 1867.663 | 1         |         |
|   150 | 1867.186 | 1         |         |
|   151 | 1867.687 | 1         |         |
|   152 | 1867.459 | 1         |         |
|   153 | 1867.168 | 1         |         |
|   154 | 1869.689 | 1         |         |
|   155 | 1869.693 | 1         |         |
|   156 | 1871.676 | 1         |         |
|   157 | 1873.174 | 1         | 1       | max
|   158 | 1873.691 | np.nan    |         |
|   159 | 1873.685 | np.nan    |         |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

I must specify upfront that this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151128/find-the-highest-and-lowest-value-locations-within-an-interval-on-a-column) with a `pandas` solution. The solution performs reasonable at about 300 seconds for a table of around 1 million rows. But after some more testing, I see that if the table is over 3 million rows, the execution time increases dramatically to over 2500 seconds and even more. This is obviously too long for such a simple task. How would the same problem be solved with `numpy`?

Comment: Shouldn't the `min` be ` 1875.73` for the second interval?

Comment: Similarly, for the last interval, the min and max look wrongly swapped.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Would you be nice if you could make those corrections, for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one NumPy approach -

```
mask = ~np.isnan(data[:,1])

s0 = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] > mask[:-1])+1
s1 = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] < mask[:-1])+1
lens = s1 - s0

tags = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lens)), lens)
idx  = np.lexsort((data[mask,0], tags))

starts = np.r_[0,lens.cumsum()]

offsets = np.r_[s0[0], s0[1:] - s1[:-1]]
offsets_cumsum = offsets.cumsum()

min_ids = idx[starts[:-1]] + offsets_cumsum
max_ids = idx[starts[1:]-1] + offsets_cumsum

out = np.full(data.shape[0], np.nan)
out[min_ids] = -1
out[max_ids] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you again @Divakar :)

Comment: Just a quick question @Divakar, if there are duplicates of the max or the min value within the interval then at the moment the script chooses the last duplicate value within the interval. How to make it to choose the first encountered max/min instead of the last one? I noticed now that in pandas it is the first one chosen whereas in here the last

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit of a cheat since it uses `scipy`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

markers = np.isnan(data[:, 1])
groups = np.cumsum(markers)

mins, max, min_idx, max_idx = ndimage.measurements.extrema(
    data[:, 0], labels=groups, index=range(2, groups.max(), 2))
```

Comment: Thank you @StephenRauch for the answer :)